# Mathematica - Function to return list

Tags: list, function, return, wolfram-mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica, and I'm trying to create an input function which would return a list of offsprings for the genetic algorithm, but the code returns

```
Null Return[{}]
```

after asking for the number of offsprings. How can I get the code to run and return the offspring list as inputted? Thanks!

```
inputData[]:= (
  i = 1
    offspring = {};
  offspringSize = Input["Enter number of offspring"];
  While[i <= offspringSize,
   n = Input[
     "Enter data in form {Potential 1, Potential 2, Number of cycles, \
Cycle Length, Wave Form, Result}"];
   offspring = Append[offspring, n];
   n =.;
   i++;
   ];
  Print[offspring]
   Return[offspring]
  );

newData = inputData[]
```

Comment: several statements are missing terminating semicolons for starters

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify this. And then show the result of entering two made up offspring.

```
In[1]:= inputData[] := (offspringSize = Input["Enter number of offspring"];
  offspring = Table[Input[
    "Enter data in form {Potential 1, Potential 2, Number of
    cycles, Cycle Length, Wave Form, Result}"], {offspringSize}];
  Print[offspring];
  offspring);

  newData = inputData[]

During evaluation of In[1]:= {{1,3,5,7,9,11},{2,4,6,8,10,12}}

Out[2]= {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}}
```